# Save multiple mssql recordsets into individual JS objects

Tags: node.js, sql-server, database, object, mssql-jdbc

Good day,
In my company I have received the order to query some data, which is queried in tabular form, with JS and later to insert it on the html page.

I don't know how to save recordsets, which are executed in a query using the "mssql" node module, into individual objects.

I tried to generate a for loop with which I tried to store the properties with their values ​​in individual intermediate variables for each recordset and insert them into individual objects using a switch case.

The result: Many more data sets are displayed in the console, i.e. something is wrong.

Now my question: Is there a simple solution to output the recordsets directly to an object like for instance with oracledb u can say "outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT"?

```js
async function getPositionen() {
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(dbconfig);
        const result = await pool.request().query("for Security reasons unfortunately no query")
        console.log(result.recordset.length)

        filterOutPositions();
        function filterOutPositions() {
           

            for (var i = 0; i <= result.recordset.length; ++i) {

                var DayNo = [];
                var Status = [];
                var Hrl = [];
                var HrlGa = [];
                var Ktl = [];
                var Ggl = [];
                var M14 = [];
                var Trl = [];
                var LzhRlw = [];
                var LzhRlz = [];
                var Mf5Pal = [];
                var Mf5Spr = [];

                DayNo = result.recordset[i].DayNo;
                Status = result.recordset[i].Status;
                Hrl = result.recordset[i].Hrl;
                HrlGa = result.recordset[i].HrlGa;
                Ktl = result.recordset[i].Ktl;
                Ggl = result.recordset[i].Ggl;
                M14 = result.recordset[i].M14;
                Trl = result.recordset[i].Trl;
                LzhRlw = result.recordset[i].LzhRlw;
                LzhRlz = result.recordset[i].LzhRlz;
                Mf5Pal = result.recordset[i].Mf5Pal;
                Mf5Spr = result.recordset[i].Mf5Spr;

                switch (i) {
                    case 0:

                        heute_offen = {
                            "DayNo": DayNo,
                            "Status": Status,
                            "Hrl": Hrl,
                            "HrlGa": HrlGa,
                            "Ktl": Ktl,
                            "Ggl": Ggl,
                            "M14": M14,
                            "Trl": Trl,
                            "LzhRlw": LzhRlw,
                            "LzhRlz": LzhRlz,
                            "Mf5Pal": Mf5Pal,
                            "Mf5Spr": Mf5Spr
                        }
                        //   console.log(heute_offen)
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        heute_erledigt = {
                            "DayNo": DayNo,
                            "Status": Status,
                            "Hrl": Hrl,
                            "HrlGa": HrlGa,
                            "Ktl": Ktl,
                            "Ggl": Ggl,
                            "M14": M14,
                            "Trl": Trl,
                            "LzhRlw": LzhRlw,
                            "LzhRlz": LzhRlz,
                            "Mf5Pal": Mf5Pal,
                            "Mf5Spr": Mf5Spr

                        }
                        //  console.log(heute_erledigt)
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        morgen_offen = {
                            "DayNo": DayNo,
                            "Status": Status,
                            "Hrl": Hrl,
                            "HrlGa": HrlGa,
                            "Ktl": Ktl,
                            "Ggl": Ggl,
                            "M14": M14,
                            "Trl": Trl,
                            "LzhRlw": LzhRlw,
                            "LzhRlz": LzhRlz,
                            "Mf5Pal": Mf5Pal,
                            "Mf5Spr": Mf5Spr
                        }
                        //   console.log(morgen_offen)
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        morgen_erledigt = {
                            "DayNo": DayNo,
                            "Status": Status,
                            "Hrl": Hrl,
                            "HrlGa": HrlGa,
                            "Ktl": Ktl,
                            "Ggl": Ggl,
                            "M14": M14,
                            "Trl": Trl,
                            "LzhRlw": LzhRlw,
                            "LzhRlz": LzhRlz,
                            "Mf5Pal": Mf5Pal,
                            "Mf5Spr": Mf5Spr
                        }
                        //   console.log(morgen_erledigt)
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        übermorgen_offen = {
                            "DayNo": DayNo,
                            "Status": Status,
                            "Hrl": Hrl,
                            "HrlGa": HrlGa,
                            "Ktl": Ktl,
                            "Ggl": Ggl,
                            "M14": M14,
                            "Trl": Trl,
                            "LzhRlw": LzhRlw,
                            "LzhRlz": LzhRlz,
                            "Mf5Pal": Mf5Pal,
                            "Mf5Spr": Mf5Spr
                        }
                        //    console.log(übermorgen_offen)
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        übermorgen_erledigt = {
                            "DayNo": DayNo,
                            "Status": Status,
                            "Hrl": Hrl,
                            "HrlGa": HrlGa,
                            "Ktl": Ktl,
                            "Ggl": Ggl,
                            "M14": M14,
                            "Trl": Trl,
                            "LzhRlw": LzhRlw,
                            "LzhRlz": LzhRlz,
                            "Mf5Pal": Mf5Pal,
                            "Mf5Spr": Mf5Spr
                        }
                        //   console.log(übermorgen_erledigt)
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        zukunft_offen = {
                            "DayNo": DayNo,
                            "Status": Status,
                            "Hrl": Hrl,
                            "HrlGa": HrlGa,
                            "Ktl": Ktl,
                            "Ggl": Ggl,
                            "M14": M14,
                            "Trl": Trl,
                            "LzhRlw": LzhRlw,
                            "LzhRlz": LzhRlz,
                            "Mf5Pal": Mf5Pal,
                            "Mf5Spr": Mf5Spr
                        }
                        //    console.log(zukunft_offen)
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        zukunft_erledigt = {
                            "DayNo": DayNo,
                            "Status": Status,
                            "Hrl": Hrl,
                            "HrlGa": HrlGa,
                            "Ktl": Ktl,
                            "Ggl": Ggl,
                            "M14": M14,
                            "Trl": Trl,
                            "LzhRlw": LzhRlw,
                            "LzhRlz": LzhRlz,
                            "Mf5Pal": Mf5Pal,
                            "Mf5Spr": Mf5Spr
                        }
                        //   console.log(zukunft_erledigt)
                        break;


                }
                /* var data = {
                     1: [DayNo, Status, Hrl, HrlGa, Ktl, Ggl, M14, Trl, LzhRlw, LzhRlz, Mf5Pal, Mf5Spr],
                    
                 }*/
                 console.log(heute_offen)
                 console.log(heute_erledigt)
                 console.log(morgen_offen)
                 console.log(morgen_erledigt)
                 console.log(übermorgen_offen)
                 console.log(übermorgen_erledigt)
                 console.log(zukunft_offen)
                 console.log(zukunft_erledigt)



            }


            /*  banana.filter(element => {
                  return element !== '';
              })
              */


            /*console.log(heute_offen)
            console.log(heute_erledigt)
            console.log(morgen_offen)
            console.log(morgen_erledigt)
            console.log(übermorgen_offen)
            console.log(übermorgen_erledigt)
            console.log(zukunft_offen)
            console.log(zukunft_erledigt)*/
        }

        //document.getElementById("hrl_heute").value = results[1]
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    sql.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I was overthinking. The simple solution:

```js
            for (var i = 0; i <= result.recordset.length; ++i) {

                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        vergangenheit_erledigt = result.recordset[0]
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        heute_offen = result.recordset[1]
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        heute_erledigt = result.recordset[2]
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        morgen_offen = result.recordset[3]
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        morgen_erledigt = result.recordset[4]
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        übermorgen_offen = result.recordset[5]
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        übermorgen_erledigt = result.recordset[6]
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        zukunft_offen = result.recordset[7]
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        zukunft_erledigt = result.recordset[8]
                        break;

                }
```

Can I probably automate the generation of the object variables like: example[i] = {}
This would be nice as in this case its static.